# Inserting 'Read More' text string inline within line-clamp

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a Read More function for a website, and I have some issues getting it to work properly. I want it to look something like this:

Text string, lorem ipsum this is dumm... Read More

If the text string is over 100 in length. When this happens, it will toggle between a button cutting it with line-clamp.

My problem is that I cannot get the ... Read More into the inline cut-out text. I have tried different methods, such as insertAdjacentHTML, :after content: '' and by textContent to name a few, but cannot get it to work proper. My code for now is as follows:

```
<div class='classname'>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue</p>   
</div>
```

```
.toggler{
display: -webkit-box!important;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
overflow: hidden!important;
  width: 50%;
}

.untoggle{
display: block!important;
 -webkit-line-clamp: none!important;
 -webkit-box-orient: none!important;
overflow: none!important;
}
```

```
var x = document.querySelector('.classname').innerText.length;
const btnAddClass = document.querySelector('.classname')
if (x > 100){
 btnAddClass.classList.add('toggler');
}

btnAddClass.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
btnAddClass.classList.toggle('untoggle');
});
```

Is there any way that I can get the ... Read More to stay after the cut text, or is it impossible the way I am trying to achieve it?

Comment: On a relatively unrelated note, I must recommend you (almost) never use `!important` in css. It's a bad practice and is likely to cause you many problems down the line. I would recommend you read up on [CSS specificity and how it is calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Yes I know, it's for a Wordpress site (using Elementor - I know even worse), so it's sadly needed quite a bit. Just forgot to sanitize it before posting here!

Comment: In your sample code, all I see happening is a class `toggler` added to the text wrapper, which seems fine, but where is your button element? I'd expect to see insertion of a new element (a "Read More") with something like [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: I make it happen through the whole element (could just be the p-tag instead of the div), so whereever you click on the text it expands